# Can his be used for feminine nouns

Tags: pronouns, antecedents

In the following sentence

> Prime Minister Narendra Modi on Tuesday met his mother Heeraben in Gandhinagar on the occasion of **his** 69th birthday.

His is used for mother. Is it correct?

Answer (score 5):

In English, "his" cannot refer to a woman or girl. When I read that sentence, I understand it to mean that Narendra Modi's own 69th birthday was on Tuesday (not his mother's birthday). If that is not what the article meant, then there is a typo in it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this sentence is correct. "His" has "PM Narendra Modi" as its antecedent, which is the noun it needs to match in terms of gender.

As long as the antecedent is male, his mother (his father, his friend, his daughter, his son, his wife) are all correct regardless of the gender of the following noun.

Answer (score 0):

Tuesday (today, September 17 2019) is ...

> ...the 69th birthday of the prime minister.

[India.com news desk](https://www.india.com/news/gujarat-pm-modi-meets-his-mother-heeraben-eats-lunch-with-her-at-gandhinagar-residence-on-69th-birthday-see-pics-3776043/)

Thus 'his' is correct. If today was his mother's 69th birthday, then 'her' would be correct. His mother is reported to be 95 years old.

Answer (score -1):

*His X* means X belongs to a person that's a male.

It doesn't say anything about the gender of X.

To get the reason why *his* is used, you have to go backwards in the sentence or conversation.

> Prime Minister Narendra Modi on Tuesday met his mother ...

*His* is used because "Prime Minister Narendra Modi" is male.

And to answer your question, absolutely *his X* can be used if X is feminine, so *his mother* is valid.

Comment: That wasn't the question. Look for the bold 'his'.